# Syntax error on token "<=", delete this token

Tags: java, syntax, token

I'm creating a program for hurricane scale, and it's giving me problems. All the error occur on the else if lines. Help would be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hurricaneScale {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the wind speed (in mph):");
    double windSpeed = in.nextln();

    if (windSpeed < 39) {
      System.out.print("      Category          Wind Speed   Storm Surge   Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Tropical Depression   < 39 mph         -            Minimal    ");
    } 
    else if (windSpeed >= 39 && <=73) {
      System.out.print("    Category           Wind Speed   Storm Surge   Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Tropical Storm      39 - 73 mph        -            Minimal    ");
    } 
    else if (windSpeed >= 74 && <=95) {
      System.out.print("   Category             Wind Speed   Storm Surge   Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Hurricane 1          74 - 95 mph   4.0' - 5.0'   Minimal to extensive");
    } 
    else if (windSpeed >= 96 && <=110) {
      System.out.print("   Category           Wind Speed   Storm Surge   Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Hurricane 2        96 - 110 mph   6.0' - 8.0'      Moderate    ");
    } 
    else if (windSpeed >= 111 && <=130) {
      System.out.print("   Category          Wind Speed      Storm Surge    Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Hurricane 3      111 - 130 mph     9.0' - 12.0'       Extensive    ");
    } 
    else if (windSpeed >= 131 && <=155) {
      System.out.print("   Category          Wind Speed      Storm Surge        Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Hurricane 4      131 - 155 mph    13.0' - 16.0'            Extreme    ");
    } 
    else if (windSpeed > 155) {
      System.out.print("   Category        Wind Speed      Storm Surge      Damage Potential");
      System.out.println("Hurricane 5      > 155 mph         > 18.0'           Catastrophic ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax is invalid:

```
else if (windSpeed >= 39 && <=73)
```

You need to replace this with:

```
else if (windSpeed >= 39 && windSpeed <=73)
```

You would have to do this for each occurance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to add `windSpeed` variable to all of your if conditions. Like this

```
windSpeed >= 39 && windSpeed <=73
```

You cannot write `windspeed >= 39 && <=73`, it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
windSpeed >= 39 && windSpeed <=73
```